# Custom builds in OpenLayers v5.x

Tags: openlayers-3

In the openlayer 3 wiki is written that from openlayers v5 the sources will be maintained as ES modules. How will the process of custom builds change?

I am asking because i have a customized version of the ol.source.TileWMS source and i need to compile the whole library including my custom source